# Branching off from currently working branch - Git

Tags: git, git-branch

We are strictly not following Gitflow workflow for Jenkins pipeline code.

There is a branch `X` from `master`, which is currently used by other technician for his own changes. There are many commits in coming weeks on branch `X`.

```
+----+------------- master
      \
       \
         -----------X (currently used by Developer A)
```

My manager asked me to create another branch `Y` on branch `X` to make my own changes. I need to make sure that, branch `X` changes are up-to-date in my branch before I start coding every day on branch `Y`

But, the problem is every day I need to merge branch `X` to be up-to-date, that leads to merge conflicts. I get these below errors, before I create any branch `Y`:

```
$ git branch
  master
* X
$
$
$ git pull origin X
error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
$
```

---

What is the best approach to work on my own branch with less merge conflicts with branch `X`?

Comment: Why are there consistent conflicts? Do you both keep changing the same files?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Query edited to answer your question. am trying to understand the consequences of creating branch `Y` off `X`...down the line, before I create create `Y`. There is a chance, branch `Y` make some changes that overlap with branch `X`

Comment: The message: `error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.` means that you're still in the middle of a *previous* merge, perhaps one invoked by a *previous* `git pull`. You must finish this previous merge before you can start any new merges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

> *What is the best approach to work on my own branch with less merge conflicts with branch X?*

Use short-lived, focused feature branches off branch X. Just because everyone else isn't doesn't mean you can't. Using short-lived feature branches off X minimizes how much X can diverge from your feature branch and reduces conflicts.

Make a branch, implement *one thing* in your branch, and merge the branch into X as quickly as possible before X can drift too far. Ideally your branches should be lasting for days if not hours.

Once you've finished your task and merged your branch, do not reuse it. Delete it. Make a new branch off X for the next task.

---

The workflow to deal with this is the same as branching from master, except you're branching from X.

Here's an illustration of your repository with Y branched off X. Y is out of date.

```
A - B [origin/master]
     \
      C - D - G - H [origin/X]
           \
            E - F [Y]
```

You've set Y to track `origin/X`.

```
$ git branch -u origin/X Y
Branch 'Y' set up to track remote branch 'X' from 'origin'.
```

Instead of merging with the upstream branch to update, I recommend rebasing. It will keep your history cleaner and make dealing with merges simpler. Run a `git pull --rebase`. Instead of fetching and merging, Git will fetch and rebase. This replays each of your commits on top of the latest version of X.

```
A - B [origin/master]
     \
      C - D - G - H [origin/X]
                   \
                    E1 - F1 [Y]
```

It's as if you were working on top of the latest X all along. This avoids building up a lot of confusing and unnecessary "update merges".

This also makes managing merge conflicts easier. Rather than having to deal with all the merge conflicts with X all at once, you can do them commit-by-commit. First you deal with conflicts between E and X. Then F and X. Splitting up conflicts per commit makes it easier to see what is conflicting and why.

You can make this the default in your `.gitconfig`. It does take some getting used to.

```
[pull]
        rebase = preserve
```

Whether you merge or rebase, resolving a conflict is the same basic process. Resolving a conflict in Git is just like a co-worker calling you over to help with an edit. Git will merge as much as it can and stage (`git add`) its work. When it comes across something it can't handle it edits the files to show what it can't handle with [conflict markers](https://wincent.com/wiki/Understanding_Git_conflict_markers) and leaves those bits unstaged and calls for a human (you) to figure it out. You edit the files to fix them, stage (`git add`) them, and tell Git to continue on to the next commit with `git rebase --continue`.

Or decide everything has gone terribly wrong and you'd like to start over with `git rebase --abort`.

Once you're done with your featuree, merge Y into X (or let Bob do it), delete Y, and start a fresh branch off X for the next feature.

---

> *There is a branch X from master, which is currently used by other technician for his own changes. There are many commits in coming weeks on branch X.*

And now an aside for why long lived and personal branches are a nightmare best avoided.

A feature branch has a clearly defined purpose and a clearly defined point when they'll get merged. In contrast, personal branches have no focus; they can just contain whatever stuff Bob happens to be working on today. And they have no end. They become long lived branches.

Long lived branches are a nightmare best avoided. As they increasingly diverge from `master` they'll pick up more and more unrelated changes and be less and less likely to ever get merged. More and more work has to go into just keeping them up to date with `master` (if they ever bother) and more and more work has to go into managing branches off branches.

The worst is a long-lived personal branch. It contains whatever stuff Bob has been working on. Who knows what changes are in there? What are they all supposed to do? Do they work? Are these changes good or bad? They're just what Bob decided to do. Merging it is an all-or-nothing leap of faith in Bob.

If possible, close branch X as quickly as possible, avoid personal branches, and move to using [short lived, clearly defined feature branches](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow). Good branch management is hard enough as it is. Everyone's lives will be much better for it.

Comment: Do I need to run `git pull --rebase` every morning?

Comment: @overexchange You run it whenever you want to update your branch on top of the latest version of X. How often you do this depends on how often X changes and how sensitive your work is to the change. You'll definitely want to do this before you complete a feature branch to make sure you're up to date. You'll also want to make sure `origin/X` is up to date before you branch off it, you can use `git fetch` for that.

Comment: @overexchange It's important to realize there is no "Git server" like other version control systems you might be used to. Everything in Git is happening locally on your machine. Instead it keeps snapshots of other people's repositories as "remotes" and stores them in "remote tracking branches". It only updates these snapshots when you tell it to. `origin/X` is your tracking branch of where branch X is on the `origin` remote last time you ran `git fetch origin`. `git pull origin X` does a `git fetch origin` and a `git merge origin/X` (or `git rebase origin/X` with `--rebase`).